# Getting an error when trying to deploy a react app to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli

As Im upgrading my react app on Heroku from stack-18 to stack-22, I m keep getting this error in Heroku logs. Not sure why it is getting error, could you please help me in the same.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/mohitkr01/create-react-app-buildpack
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 18.x...
       Downloading and installing node 18.12.1...
       Using default npm version: 8.19.2
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code 1
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/node-sass
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/build.js
       npm ERR! Building: /tmp/build_11bc449b/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
       npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/tmp/build_11bc449b/.heroku/node/bin/node',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
       npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
       npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
       npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | linux | x64
       npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
       npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
       npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
       npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
       npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21) {
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
       npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
       npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:412:12)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1104-aws
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_11bc449b/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_11bc449b/node_modules/node-sass
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
       npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.dUlwP/_logs/2022-12-16T06_53_44_046Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
 !     Push failed
```

Although here is my Package.json, it seems to be good to me

`

```
{
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.2",
    "ionicons": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "4.x",
    "react": "17.x",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have no idea why it cant resolve the file, as it is located exactly where i specified. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance